# CPAssembler error: Web control file is not located inside your website error

Tags: content-delivery, dynamic-linking

I'm getting this error:

> CPAssembler error: Web control file is not located inside your website

when I check my page in my browser.

The page conains a single Component Presentation, with the "Allow on Page Using Dynamic Assembly" box checked.

[image]

I've checked the source code of the page rendered and it is:
    `<tridion:ComponentPresentation runat="server" PageURI="tcm:69-13075-64" ComponentURI="tcm:69-13070" TemplateURI="tcm:69-13071-32"/>`

Also I've checked the cd_storage_conf.xml and it has:

```
<Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="defaultFile" defaultFilesystem="false">
            <Root Path="D:\Websites\staging" />
        </Storage>
        <Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="defaultDataFile" defaultFilesystem="true" defaultStorage="true">             
            <Root Path="D:\Websites\staging\data" />
        </Storage>
```

I'm using Tridion 2011 SP1

Does anyone have an idea of the cause of this error?

Comment: Is this a possible duplicate? Have you already followed all of the suggestions here: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/2880/?

Comment: Hi Jonahathan, yes, I did and I coudn't fix it

Comment: Carolina, would you please edit your question with the error in the body? Currently the error is briefly mentioned only in the title. It will help with readability for others. Also, if there is a stacktrace in the log with additional info please add this detail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fact that you are seeing the correct `<tridion:ComponentPresentation runat="server" ... />` tag indicates that the `Language` of your `Publishing Target` is set up correctly (ASP.NET) and that your Deployer is configured to transform the Component Presentations' TCDL tags to the correct (.NET) format.

It is difficult without seeing the rest of your config file, but you should check that you have a specific Item Type Mapping for (Dynamic) Component Presentations:

```
<Item typeMapping="ComponentPresentation" itemExtension=".ascx" storageId="defaultDataFile"/>
```

This will need to be present in the `cd_storage_conf.xml` that your website uses, as well as the one used by the Deployer.

You may also want to double-check that you .ascx User Controls definitely are being published into that directory (`D:\Websites\staging\data`) too. These will not work if the .ascx files are not located inside of a sub-folder of you main site folder.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, thanks for hel me. I have the code into the `cd_storage_conf.xml`, it is: `<Item typeMapping="Page" cached="false" storageId="defaultFile"/>
  <Item typeMapping="Binary" cached="false" storageId="defaultFile"/>
  <Item typeMapping="ComponentPresentation" itemExtension=".Ascx" storageId="defaultDataFile"/>` and I've checked the syste foler and I have the .ascx into this folder : D:\Websites\staging\data\pub69

Comment: Hi @Jonathan Williams, you were right !! the problem was with (`D:\Websites\staging\data`), because it is a folder out of the main website, I setup a new folder inside the website and now everything is working fine. Thanks so much !!!!

Comment: super - I'm glad it worked!